# Excel VBA: Checking if the values in a table exist in a different range [like an error check function], plus locating unmatched item

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function and a procedure that calls on such a function to check if names of the items located in a large table of repetitive data appear on a different sheet that's basically sort of like an input sheet for a user or a set up sheet. Basically the code should catch misspellings and unmatched items in the table on Sheet2 vs. a range on Sheet1. Ideally I would want to add an ability for the code to stop on an unmatched item and maybe highlight it so that user could correct an error or research the issue further. Currently I've tried to write the first part of the code but something is not working. It always says item name doesn't exists no matter how i set up data in the table:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ItemNameExists(Target As String) As Boolean

Dim lookUp As Excel.Range
Dim itemCell As Excel.Range

ItemNameExists = False

Set lookUp = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1[Items]")
For Each itemCell In lookUp
    If (itemCell.Value = Target) Then
        ItemNameExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

End Function

Sub CheckErrors()

Dim ItemName As Excel.Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set ItemName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B12")

For Each Cell In ItemName
    If (Len(Cell.Value) > 0) Then
        If (Not ItemNameExists(Cell.Value)) Then
        MsgBox ("Item name doesn't exist on Sheet1")
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For searching a `Range` there is a specific method, `Range.Find` (official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).
If no match is found, it returns `Nothing`.

As to your case, there are quite a few points where it may miss the target, so you would probably have to debug:

1. Make sure `lookUp` actually refers to the intended `Range`.
2. Make sure `Target` contains the intended text.
3. Try with `itemCell.Text` instead of `itemCell.Value` (if you still prefer not to use `Range.Find`).